# Running MySQL query from class. Values not being passed on to class properly

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Here it is.

-I have a window. And I have a class.

-The window is a password login window so it has a textbox for the username, a passwordbox and a login button.

Code behind this window:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Masca
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Login.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Login : Elysium.Controls.Window
{

    InvalidLogin secondForm;

    // This window now knows that the loginc class exists. The class hold all MySQL related code
    public loginc loginc;

    // THis window now knows about the MainWindow. This is the window that will be opened after authetication checks are successful.
    MainWindow window;

    // The login window is now publically available to other windows.
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //This is the event that is carried out when the user clicks 'Login'
    public void Logon_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // instantiate the class
        loginc = new loginc();

        //Check to see if the username is blank
        if (username.Text == "")
        {
            //If it is, show the custom dialogue box "nousername"
            new nousername().ShowDialog();
        }
        //Then check to see if the password is blank
        else if (password.Password == "")
        {
            //If it is, show the custom dialogue box "nopassword"
            new nopassword().ShowDialog();
        }
        // However if they both have content..
        else if (username.Text != "" && password.Password != "")
        {
            // Trigger this method in the loginc class.
            loginc.Login();
        }
    }

    // This method is triggered by the login method in the loginc class if the credentials are valid
    public void login()
    {
        window = new MainWindow(username.Text);
        window.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    // This method is also triggered by the login method in the loginc class but only if the credentials are not valid
    public void failLogin()
    {
        //If the entered username and password does not matchup with any record in the database, show the error messagebox 'InvalidLogin';
        secondForm = new InvalidLogin();

        //The form that opened the dialoge box is 'Login', the login window;
        secondForm.setCreatingForm = this;

        // Keep that in mind when you show the dialogue box;
        secondForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

-The class holds the MySQL code that will be used to check the username and password  inside the database.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Masca
{
public class loginc
{
    //This class now knows about the login window.
    public Login login;

    // Constructor
    public loginc()
    {

    }

    // This method is triggered by the 'Logon_Click' event in the Login window
    public void Login ()
    {
        //instantiate the Login window
        login = new Login();

        //Database connection parameters
        string sqlcon = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username = root; password = root";
        //Query to excecute
        string query = "SELECT * FROM logon.login where username = '"+login.username.Text+"' and password = '"+login.password.Password+"';";

        //Declarations
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand (query,con);
        MySqlDataReader rdr;

        // Excecution
        con.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        // If the username and password matches a record in the database table..
        if (count == 1)
        {
            //Trigger the login method in the login window
            login.login();
        }

        // Otherwise...
        else 
        {
            //Trigger the failLogin method in the login window
            login.failLogin();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

So the problem? Everytime I enter the right or wrong credentials to log in, I get the invalid credentials dialogue box.

I'm guessing (I might be wrong) it's most likely because of the classes I instantiated. The details I refer to (in the query) +login.username.Text+ and +login.password.Password+ in the class, are collected from a different instance of the login window than the one I entered them in. Hence the details it collects are blanks.

It also might explain why when I replace +login.username.Text+ and +login.password.Password+ with the actual credentials in the login table, the login window stays open even after the MainWindow opens, when I've programed it to close. Because it closes a different instance entirely.

Even with all this speculation of mine, I still don't know a feasible solution to this problem of mine. The only one I can think of is having static classes using the singleton pattern to ensure the program only ever have one instance of a classes and windows at run time. I'm not too sure where to start with that one though.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of passing parameters to and returning values from a function?

Comment: I smell SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let your `loginc.Login()` method take the `Login` window as a parameter, and use that instead of creating a new one;

That is, change;

```
public void Login ()
{
    //instantiate the Login window
    login = new Login();
```

into

```
public void Login (Login login)
{
    // you now have the existing login window as "login".
```

and call it as;

```
loginc.Login(this);  // pass this object (the Login window) as a parameter
```

Another (possibly better) way is to pass the login and password as strings to `loginc.Login()`, that way the `loginc` class doesn't need to know about the fields in the `Login` class at all.

You should also *really* look into parameterizing your query, a `'` in one of the login boxes will break your query and allow someone to write their own SQL directly against your database.

([Here you can read up a little on SQL injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/459324/Understading-SQL-Injection-and-Creating-SQL-Inject))

Comment: I went for your 1st suggestion and it worked like a charm. Much gratitude. Taking a look at the link too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all and more important your SQL statement is exposed to injection you have to use parameters in your query. SAve the creadentials as static vars an pass them in login form as parameters:

in First Form:

```
public partial class Login : Elysium.Controls.Window
{
....
....
 else if (username.Text != "" && password.Password != "")
{
// Trigger this method in the login class.
loginc.Login();        
loginc.username=username.Text;
loginc.pass=password.Password;
}
....
```

in Second Form:

```
public class loginc
{
  public static username;
  public static pass;
...
...
 string query = "SELECT * FROM logon.login where username = @user and password = @pass";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@user,username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@pass,pass);
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Trying this out.

Comment: Seems like I got an error in my class on "public static username **;** " and "public static pass **;** " Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. Not too sure how to fix that... Did I miss something?